# How to target only the ID in the div with addClass on a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to only target the div associated with the checkbox. Right now the script I am using only changes the class of the first div with the ID of taskList instead of the one where the checkbox is located.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#taskList').addClass("complete");
    } else {
        $('#taskList').removeClass("complete");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML in your question too?

Comment: ids should be unique!

Comment: I think with seeing the HTML, we can't decide that he use multiple id as same name.

Comment: OP said **only changes the class of the first div with the ID of taskList instead of the one where the checkbox is located**. From this it is clear he is using multiple id as same name. @FrayneKonok

Comment: okey, i think this is right. But @Cody, don't say anything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` should be unique each element. Use class `taskList` instead like following.

```js
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('.taskList').addClass("complete");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.taskList').removeClass("complete");
    }
});
```

```css
.complete {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="taskList">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div class="taskList">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for not providing HTML, but this works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you should us [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) over here.

Suppose you have html like this:-

```
<div class="taskList">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
<div class="taskList">
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div
```

> Now what colsest will do is, it goes for each element in the set, get
>   the first element that matches the selector by testing the element
>   itself.

so on check ( change ) you should do,

```
$(this).closest('.taskList').addClass("yourClass");
```

Full code goes,

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest('.taskList').addClass("yourClass");
    } else {
        $(this).closest('.taskList').removeClass("yourClass");
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!